# Solving for derivatives, left-hand and right-hand, open and closed interval

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let f(x)=|5+6x|
.
Then for x<−56
, f′(x)=
.
The left-hand derivative of f(x)
at x=−56
is
.
The right-hand derivative of f(x)
at x=−56
is
.
Is f(x)
differentiable at x=−56
? Answer (Y/N):

Mark the following statements T or F, according as to whether they are true or false:
f(x)
is differentiable on the closed interval (−∞,−56]

f(x)
is differentiable on the open interval (−∞,−56)

f(x)
is differentiable on the closed interval [−56,∞)

f(x)
is differentiable on the open interval (−56,∞)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Note that questions showing no effort tend to be voted down, and are closed. Also, please use MathJax to format any mathematical expression

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics at this site.  Do you mean $-56$ or $-\frac{5}{6}$?.